# Concatenate columns of strings, where the column names are in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I know how to concatenate two columns of strings.

`df['a'] + ' ' + df['b']`

but if I have a long list of column names I can't write all that out.

This is obviously incorrect but I was thinking something along the lines of...

`' '.join([df[col] for col in columns])`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use DataFrame.sum specifying the correct axis and it will join together strings.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['hello', 'goodbye'], '34234': ['goodbye', 'seven'], 
                   'column2': ['foo-', 'bird'], 'column xx': ['bar', 'cat']})
#         a    34234 column2 column xx
#0    hello  goodbye    foo-       bar
#1  goodbye    seven    bird       cat
```

---

```
columns = ['a', 'column2', 'column xx']
(df[columns] + ' ').sum(axis=1).str.strip()  # strip removes the trailing space
```

Outputs:

```
0      hello foo- bar
1    goodbye bird cat
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple summing function yourself (the built-in `sum` works only with numbers):

```
def concat(df, cols):
    out = df[cols[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(cols)):
        out = out + df[cols[i]]  # Note: `+=` would change the first column.
    return out
```

Answer (score 0):

I've no experience with pandas, but could you not do:

```
' '.join(df[i] for i in columns.keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

df.columns will give all the columns. Do concatenate.

```
 ' '.join(df.columns)
```

Comment: This just joins the column names, not the values in the columns.

Comment: Also raises `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found` on numbered columns.